# How to Extract .owl and save to mysql

Tags: owl, semantic-web

I have a file **ontobible.owl**. how to extract that file  and then save data to mysql (because I want display data from ontobible.owl in website). can anyone help me?

edited:
here is my ontobible.owl file (https://teamtrainit.com/ontobible.owl)

i've try open ontobible.owl  with sublime text 3 and contains like this

```
<Verse rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/budsus/ontologies/2021/7/ontobible#HOS5_2">
    <verseID>HOS5_2</verseID>
    <verse_text>And the revolters are profound to make slaughter, though I have been a rebuker of them all.</verse_text>
  </Verse>
  <Verse rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/budsus/ontologies/2021/7/ontobible#2CH2_1">
    <hasPerson rdf:resource="http://semanticbible.org/ns/2006/NTNames#god_1324"/>
    <hasPerson rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/roberts/family-tree.owl#solomon_2762"/>
    <verseID>2CH2_1</verseID>
    <verse_text>And Solomon determined to build an house for the name of the LORD, and an house for his kingdom.</verse_text>
  </Verse>
```

how to convert that xml tag to array or json so I cant save it to mysql database

Comment: "extract that file"??? you have that file, what do you want to "extract"? I also don't get why you want to load an OWL ontology to a MySQL database? Why can't you use the data directly from the file or use an API for OWL? And if you want to load the OWL ontology into a relational database, obviously you have to define some schema in advance

Comment: long story short, I thing you should start again, take notes of requirements - sounds more like an x/y problem currently

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its current form. You need to explain which data you wish to save to the database and how you extracted data from the file. There isn't just one way of taking data from an OWL file and putting it in a database.

Comment: @UninformedUser
i've edited my question, all i need is convert xml tag from that file to array or json so I cant save it to mysql database

Comment: @ArifNurRohman Have you considered to store this data into a triplestore instead? E.g. Apache Jena. It's a graph database that can power your website but does not require converting the data from the OWL (RDF actually) graph data format into relational SQL model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have several options for extracting data from owl

1. use owl-api and write java code (i think owl api is accessible in other languages) to extract data and pack it in the format you need. also you can use sparql queries for extracting data via jena api
2. install protege, open your file in protege and save it in format json-dl. this format is very similar to the regular json and you can easily transform it for your needs
3. install fuseki server, add your file and using sparql queries extract data from there

i think that the second option is the easiest for start if you don't want to write queries or code and it won't take long